# executable failing in malloc_y function

Tags: c, unix, memory, memory-management, hp-ux

We are trying to port our application from HP machine to AIX machine.

It was running fine on HP machine but now its failing in malloc_y function.
but we cant find any clue for this.

who is calling this malloc_y function?

Comment: Need much more info than that? Don't you have a stacktrace or something like that?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that malloc on AIX is just the public interface where the underlying implementation is malloc_y. To answer your question, malloc is calling malloc_y. What you probably want to know is why it's core dumping (just a hunch). I'd put my money on a double free because I don't think malloc on AIX is thread safe. And I'm guessing your application is multithreaded.

Good luck.
Tracy.